# C error : assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

I have developed a C code for my module but when I try to compile it, an error occurs.

This is the part of program where the error exist :

```
ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {
    struct file *f = pfile->private_data;
    enum { MAX_BUF_SIZE = 4096 };
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t rc = 0;

    struct input_event  ev[buf_size];
    int yalv;

    /* Allocate temporary buffer. */
    if (length) {
        buf_size = min_t(size_t, MAX_BUF_SIZE, length);
        ev = kmalloc(buf_size, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (ev == NULL) {
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    }
```

And this is the error :

```
exer_simple_char_drv.c:77:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
         ev = kmalloc(buf_size, GFP_KERNEL);
            ^
```

I don't know how to solve this. Could anyone help me out please. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back and go back to your text books to read about arrays and pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You cannot assign to a whole array, only to its elements. You therefore cannot dynamically allocate memory for a variable of *bona fide* array type such as you are using, so it's a good thing that you do not need to do.  The size of an array is fully determined by its elements type and length, and the language provides for both appropriate allocation and appropriate deallocation for objects declared as arrays.

Comment: I'm interested in helping people help themselves, which I think often gives a better learning experience. With the code you show and the error you get you show that you have a misunderstanding in some very basic C knowledge, which is why I think you need to refresh that part of the knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allocate memory for `ev` dynamically, as in:

```
ev = kmalloc(buf_size, GFP_KERNEL);
```

then you want `ev` to be a pointer, not an array with automatic storage duration:

```
struct input_event *ev;
```

Comment: And remember that the size provided to `kmalloc` is the size in *bytes* not array elements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, there should probably be a `sizeof(struct input_event)` (or equivalent) somewhere in the calculation of `buf_size`.